What is the difference between model space and object space in a realitykit composer pro material shader?
I am writing a material shader using Apple's Reality Composer Pro.
I am most comfortable working with OpenGL's GLSL where you have model space, view
space, and clip (i.e. projection) space. I would normally think model space
and object space are synonymous, but as you can see in the figure below, I can place
certain coordinates (the Bitangent in this case) in either model or object space.
What is the difference?

